# Flutter Button selection starting wrong place in Gridview on Tv App

Tags: flutter, dart, button, gridview, android-tv

[wrong selection start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPahk.png)
I open the channel list and press the down arrow, but the button selection starts from the bottom. I tried the reverse command for gridview. Then it starts from the top but from the middle of the list.
[wrong selection start reverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peaci.png)
I would be grateful if you help.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: RawKeyboardListener(
        autofocus: false,
        focusNode: FocusNode(), // <-- more magic
        onKey: (event) {
          print(event.data.logicalKey);
          if (visible == false) {
            if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyUpEvent') {
              if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
                int index =
                    live.indexWhere((item) => item.link == widget.url);
                print(index);
                print(widget.url);
                index = index - 1;
                print(index);
                print(index);
                print('livin uzunluğu ${live.length}');
                if (index < 0) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => watchStream2(
                              url: live.last.link,
                              FilmOrLive: 'Live',
                            )),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                  );
                } else {
                  String newUrl = live.elementAt(index).link.toString();
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => watchStream2(
                              url: newUrl,
                              FilmOrLive: 'Live',
                            )),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                  );
                }
              }
              if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
                int index =
                    live.indexWhere((item) => item.link == widget.url);
                print(index);
                print(widget.url);
                index = index + 1;
                print(index);
                print(index);
                print('livin uzunluğu ${live.length}');
                if (index > live.length - 1) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => watchStream2(
                              url: live.first.link,
                              FilmOrLive: 'Live',
                            )),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                  );
                } else {
                  String newUrl = live.elementAt(index).link.toString();
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => watchStream2(
                              url: newUrl,
                              FilmOrLive: 'Live',
                            )),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                  );
                }
                print('yukarı');
                setState(() {});
              }
              if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {}
              if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {}
            }
          }
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            YoYoPlayer2(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              url: widget.url,
              videoStyle2: VideoStyle2(
                qualityStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                forwardAndBackwardBtSize: 30.0,
                playButtonIconSize: 40.0,
                playIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.play_circle,
                  size: 40.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                pauseIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.pause_circle,
                  size: 40.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                videoQualityPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              ),
              videoLoadingStyle: VideoLoadingStyle(
                loading: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )),
              ),
              allowCacheFile: true,
              onCacheFileCompleted: (files) {
                print('Cached file length ::: ${files?.length}');

                if (files != null && files.isNotEmpty) {
                  for (var file in files) {
                    print('File path ::: ${file.path}');
                  }
                }
              },
              onCacheFileFailed: (error) {
                print('Cache file error ::: $error');
              },
            ),
            RawKeyboardListener(
              autofocus: true,
              focusNode: FocusNode(), // <-- more magic
              onKey: (event) {
                print(event.data.logicalKey);
                if (visible == false) {
                  if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
                    if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.select) {
                      visible = true;
                      setState(() {});
                    }
                  }
                }
                if (visible == true) {
                  if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyUpEvent') {
                    if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
                      myFocusNode;
                    }
                    if (event.data.logicalKey ==
                        LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
                      myFocusNode;
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              child: Visibility(
                  visible: visible,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 100),
                        child: GridView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

                            primary: true,
                            reverse: true,
                            // Pitch between vertical widgets

                            // GridView within the margin
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            // Widget quantity
                            // sub-Widget wide proportion
                            // Subwood list
                            gridDelegate:
                            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 1,
                                mainAxisSpacing:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                    1000,
                                childAspectRatio: 4),
                            children: live.map((ml) {
                              return ElevatedButton(
                                autofocus: true,
                                focusNode: myFocusNode,
                                onPressed: null,
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: LinearBorder.end()),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    InkWell(
                                        focusColor: Colors.red,
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    watchStream2(
                                                      url: ml.link,
                                                      FilmOrLive: 'Live',
                                                    )),
                                                (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                                          );
                                        },
                                        child: Ink(
                                            child: Card(
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  side: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.transparent),
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                      Radius.circular(10))),
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width /
                                                    1,
                                                height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height /
                                                    11,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.indigo[900],
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.all(
                                                        Radius.circular(10))),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: MediaQuery.of(
                                                              context)
                                                              .size
                                                              .width /
                                                              75,
                                                          right: MediaQuery.of(
                                                              context)
                                                              .size
                                                              .width /
                                                              50),
                                                      child: Align(
                                                        alignment:
                                                        Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                        child: Container(
                                                            width: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .width /
                                                                25,
                                                            child:
                                                            CachedNetworkImage(
                                                              imageUrl: ml.assets,
                                                              placeholder: (context,
                                                                  url) =>
                                                              new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                              errorWidget: (context,
                                                                  url,
                                                                  error) =>
                                                              new Icon(Icons
                                                                  .error),
                                                            )),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Center(
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        ml.name,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .width /
                                                                90,
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                            fontStyle:
                                                            FontStyle.italic),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ))),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Selection must start from the top and the list order must be correct